# Social media sharing only shows Twitter

Tags: civievent, social-media

We've had social media sharing for our events ("Allow sharing through social media?") enabled "forever".

Now it only shows the twitter birdie. Inspecting the page reveals that there is some code there for each of G+, Facebook and LinkedIN, but nothing shows.

We are running CiviCRM 5.13.4 on Joomla 3.9.6.

I can't find any indication that it should be configurable somewhere either.

How do I get my Social Media Sharing Icons/Links back?

Comment: It's displaying on the public demo, e.g. https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=3. If you just resave the event config does that help?

Comment: Always forget to check there. But found that it was missing there too. So, yes, it was my adblocker... ;-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out that it was the browser's adblocker that made the icons disappear.